# how to use tsparticles json file that i export from https://particles.js.org/

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I will try to use tsparticles JSON file in my react project that I export from https://particles.js.org/. but it was not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have used particle js in my project. In my project, I have made a separate component and called this component inside the main component like the App.js

And I have made the JSON file as an API. If you want to make the JSON file into an API or also you can directly call this API.

```
import React from "react";
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";
const ParticleAnimation = () => {
  const particlesInit = async (main) => {
    console.log(main);
    await loadFull(main);
  };

  const particlesLoaded = (container) => {
    console.log(container);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Particles
        id="tsparticles"
        url={YOUR_JSON_FILE_LINK_HERE}
        init={particlesInit}
        loaded={particlesLoaded}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParticleAnimation;
```